# Вопрос по верстке, почему не показыается картинка?

Tags: html

Приведу сайт http://lydmila-mebel.ru/catalog/
В шапке есть фото, оно в фаерфоксе показывается, а в хроме только узкая полоска.

Я понял что это из-за свойства: .header_block img {display: block;} но я не могу понять что ему надо написать что бы оно показывалось так же как и в фаерфоксе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Его сдвигает `.wrapper_header_block`. Можете поставить ему position: absolute, но, наскольк опонимаю, правильным будет решать это через background-image.